# In react native wix navigation how to go to previous tab from another tab?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation(wix) and I have 4 root tabs in my app. I'd like to navigate back to my previous tabs when I go from one tab to another.

Comment: have you checked out the `push` and `pop` methods for the navigator

Comment: you can store tabs index in variable like `currentTabIndex = 2` and then: `navigator.switchToTab({
    tabIndex: currentTabIndex
});`

Comment: Could you show a code snippet about this approach? Sorry, I'm new to react-native...

Answer (score 1):

This is Cherniv's answer. But basically what' he's saying is that every tab has an index. From 0 to N.

So by doing this will achieve it.

```
this.props.navigator.switchToTab({ 
    tabIndex: desiredIndex 
});
```

In the meantime, Kudos to him for helping me aswell. Thanks @Cherniv.